# Как определить, происходит ли отладка?

Tags: c, arm

Как гарантировано определить, происходит ли в данный момент отладка процессора ARM? Пробовал проверять бит C_DEBUGEN регистра DHCSR, но у него иногда бывают ложные срабатывания.

```
#define UNDER_DEBUG (CoreDebug->DHCSR & CoreDebug_DHCSR_C_DEBUGEN_Msk )
```

---

UPD. Возможно, я ошибся насчёт ложных срабатываний. Задача возникла из-за необходимости использовать порт D4, который совмещён с отладочным интерфейсом. В режиме отладки контроллер не должен задействовать этот порт, а в обычном режиме он должен работать нормально. Для этого я и пытаюсь определить, находится ли контроллер в режиме отладки. Вывод о ложных срабатываниях я сделал исходя из состояния порта, которое видел на осциллографе. Возможно, по состоянию регистра DHCSR действительно можно правильно определить режим, сложно сказать однозначно.